# An example for affine function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I'm looking for an example of a non-Euclidean non-compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ such that we could define a non-constant affine function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, namely its gradient vector field is a killing vector field.

Comment: Looks unlikely, as the minimum of $f$ is a sink of the gradient, if we ignore degeneracies.

Comment: @FanZheng I changed my question a little bit.

Comment: What does "affine function" mean in this context?

Comment: @DeaneYang I mean its gradient vector field is a killing vector field.

Comment: @MortezaAzad probably you mean noncompact?

Comment: This really is not a research-level question.  You should ask it on MathStackExchange or work it out yourself, assuming that you have had the first couple of weeks of a course in differential geometry.

Comment: @FanZheng Yes. I added the missed condition.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the manifold $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}$ with the product metric. Define $f:\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(z,t)=t.$ Then it is clear that $Hess(f)=0,$ that is, $\nabla f$ is a Killing vector field.

Note that if $M$ is compact then such a function doesn't exist. Indeed, you have $\Delta f\equiv 0.$ Thus,

$$0=\frac 12 \int_M \Delta f^2=\int_M f\Delta f+\int_M |\nabla f|^2=\int_M |\nabla f|^2,$$ from where one gets that $f$ must be constant.

Comment: A harmonic function on a compact manifold is constant. QED.